# Deleting data on RealTime Database - Firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using firebase realtime database and has following rules setup for the database,

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

But when I try to delete an entry, it gives me an error saying permission denied as follows.

```
Database: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. (database/permission-denied).
```

What should I do? I can't understand why I can do all the reads and writes pretty oki with the current rules and not delete.

Can anyone help me with this?

Note:
Image of the results related to the Firebase Simulator

[image]

When checked for the `firebase.auth().currentUser` :

```
deleteUserAccount(userId) {
 let knownLocationRef = this.database.ref('lastKnown/' + userId);
 let promises = [];
 console.log('auth details', this.auth.currentUser);
 console.log('auth details null', this.auth.currentUser !== null); //returns true
         knownLocationRef.once('value').then( (data) => {
            console.log('data ', data.val());
            if (data.val() !== null) {
                let prevLat = data.val().lat;
                let prevLong = data.val().long;
                console.log('auth details', this.auth.currentUser);
                console.log('auth details null', this.auth.currentUser !== null); //returns false
                promises.push(knownLocationRef.remove());
            }
        });
         return Promise.all(promises);
 }
```

Comment: `auth != null` means that the client is authenticated using the [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) module.  Auth adds a token to all the requests to show that they are logged in.

Comment: @JamesPoag - Yes, I understand that. And I have configured Firebase Auth and the user who is trying to delete data is authenticated as well. User can read and write data to the database without an issue.

Comment: Hmmm.  Do you know how to use the Database rules simulator in the firebase console?  Try writing a null value to a branch to simulate deleting (removing).

Comment: @JamesPoag: Yes I tried that too. But then am getting Simulated Write allowed. Since I can't add an image on the comment regarding the simulator, I will update the question with an image of the simulated results

Comment: Which client SDK are you using?  Can you perform a write with `null` instead of remove/delete? (For debugging purposes)

Comment: I'm using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase). Will get back to you regarding writing a null value

Comment: @JamesPoag: I tried writing a null. I didn't get any errors, and I didn't see any change in the DB side as well because it's a null

Comment: I'm downloading the starter kit from RNFirebase to try and reproduce.  Are you deploying to iOS or Android?

Comment: Also, are you using Anonymous authentication?

Comment: I'm deploying this on android only. But do not use Anonymous authentication

Comment: what authentication are you using?

Comment: In your code example you posted,`return Promise.all(promises);` will be executed before `promises.push(knownLocationRef.remove());`.  You need to either return the `knownLocationRef.once('value').then ...` promise or push that outer promise into your promises array.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues with your code and how you are handling promises:

```
function deleteUserAccount(userId) {
  let knownLocationRef = this.database.ref('lastKnown/' + userId);
  let promises = []; // good idea for collecting a list of distinct 
                     // promises, maybe not here

  // This is a promise, 'then' is a continuation from which you can return 
  // either a data result or another promise
  knownLocationRef.once('value').then((data) => {
    // if data is valid, return another promise
    if (data.val() !== null) {
      // ...

      // If you were looping and collecting promises, then this might help, 
      // but you don't want to collect inner promises.
      promises.push(knownLocationRef.remove());
    }
  });

  // This returns before everything in `.then` executes
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Here's a fixed version:

```
function deleteUserAccount(userId) {
  let knownLocationRef = this.database.ref('lastKnown/' + userId);
  let promises = []; // For the sake of argument, I will use this to collect 
                     // outer promises.

  // normally I would return here, but as an example, I'll uses the 
  // promises array
  promises.push(knownLocationRef.once('value').then((data) => {
    // if data is valid, return another promise
    if (data.val() !== null) {
      // ...

      // Return a Promise from a promise
      return knownLocationRef.remove();
    }

    return null; // no data to process
  }));

  // wait on outer promises
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .catch(console.log); // log errors from any promise
}
```

Here is a version without the extra `promises` array.

```
function deleteUserAccount(userId) {
  let knownLocationRef = this.database.ref('lastKnown/' + userId);

  return knownLocationRef.once('value')
    .then((data) => {
      // if data is valid, return another promise
      if (data.val() !== null) {

        // Return a Promise from a promise
        return knownLocationRef.remove();
      }

      return null; // no data to process
    })
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the issue with the `firebase.auth().currentUser` check results. I can't understand why it becomes null inside the method and not null outside the method

Comment: As an aside, [ESLint for React Native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-native) is a very useful linter that will catch some of these mistakes.  It tries to encourage proper usage of promises.